# Is it possible to dynamically change the PXSelect a view is using programatically?

Tags: acumatica

I have a button in which, when pressed, I want to show or hide rows in a grid based on certain criteria. Is it possible to change the PXSelect a view uses on the fly so that it re-queries the database and retrieves different results? I will, of course, be querying the same table and not changing up the structure of the View or grid.

Comment: possible option could be to use a filter on the graph and have your view link to the filter current value. your button can set the filter current values and might show the correct results?

Comment: Is there a good source of information to look into the PXFilter other than the information provided in the T### books?

Comment: Joshua has posted an answer that should help. His answer uses a view delegate to limit the results. You should also be able to set your BQL in the view itself to use the filter (Current<MyFilter.field>) to get the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below adds a non-visible field to the header record that is set by the button press this value is then used by the child records view delegate to determine based on the child records criteria (in this case a Boolean on each child) if they are shown.

```
public sealed class APInvoiceExtension : PXCacheExtension<APInvoice>
    {
        #region UsrShowAll 
        public abstract class usrShowAll : IBqlField
        {
        }
        [PXBool]
        public bool? UsrShowAll { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }

    public sealed class APTranExtension : PXCacheExtension<APTran>
    {
        #region UsrHidden
        public abstract class usrHidden : IBqlField
        {
        }
        [PXDBBool]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Hidden", Enabled = false)]
        public bool? UsrHidden { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }


    public class APInvoiceEntryExtension : PXGraphExtension<APInvoiceEntry>
    {

        public PXAction<APInvoice> SHW;

        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Show All Records", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Update, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Update)]
        [PXButton]
        protected void sHW()
        {
            if (Base.Document.Current != null)
            {
                APInvoiceExtension docExt = Base.Document.Current.GetExtension<APInvoiceExtension>();

                docExt.UsrShowAll = !(docExt.UsrShowAll ?? false);
            }
        }

        protected virtual IEnumerable transactions()
        {
            bool showAll = Base.Document.Current != null ? (Base.Document.Current.GetExtension<APInvoiceExtension>().UsrShowAll ?? false) : false;

            APTran tran;

            foreach (PXResult<APTran, POReceiptLine> res in Base.Transactions.Select())
            {
                tran = res[0] as APTran;

                if (!showAll)
                {
                    if (!(tran.GetExtension<APTranExtension>().UsrHidden ?? false))
                    {
                        yield return res;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    yield return res;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay on response. I was working on a different project. This worked perfectly! Thank you!